# sql to check if only entry with that value

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, sql-delete, delete-row

I have a table looking as follows: (with a few more irrelevant rows)

```
| user_id | user_name  | fk_role_id|      password|
|       1 |        us1 |     1     |    1234      | 
|       2 |        us2 |     2     |    1234      |
|       3 |        us3 |     2     |    1234      |
|       4 |        us4 |     4     |    1234      |
```

I need to form/create an SQL statement that is counting the amount of entries with the fk_role_id of 1.

If there is more than one user with that fk_role_id, it can delete that user, but if there is only one user with fk_role_id it will fail, or give an error message stating that, that user is the last one with that fk_role_id and therefore it can't be deleted.

So far I have not found anything anywhere near that, that works. So hopefully someone in here will be able to help me quickly.

Comment: Are you using MySQL or MS SQL Server? Don't tag products not involved.

Comment: Your question cannot be understood. Please re-frame it.

Comment: re-framed to hopefully something that makes more sense

Comment: SQL is not a procedural language, so constructs like `when it fails, it gives an error message` do not apply here. You rather seek a query that deletes all the records meeting certain criteria and returns some resultset about what records were/were not deleted and why.

Answer (score 0):

SQL server (2008 onwards):

```
with CTE as
(
select MT.*, row_number() over(partition by fk_role_id order by user_id) as rn
from MyTable MT
)
delete 
from CTE
where rn >1
```

Answer (score 0):

please try this statement.

```
DELETE TOP (1) FROM table_name WHERE fk_role_id= (SELECT fk_role_id 
FROM table_name GROUP BY fk_role_id HAVING COUNT(fk_role_id)>1)
```

Each time the statement is executed it deletes the top row till last only one record is left. For the last record, Having condition fails and hence it will not be deleted from your table.

Comment: i need to form it so, that it deletes the wanted user and not just the top one. i have multiply users and some of them is given the fk_role_id of 1. but i may need to delete some specific and not just the top entry of the table.

hope it make sense